# inserting element in 2D Array List

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to insert element in an ArrayList .
The elements are not being added and I cannot find why.

Here is what I have:

t[0][0] => Account

t[0][1] => Balance

```
class Banking4
    {

    int i=0;
    ArrayList[][] t = new ArrayList[2][10];
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    void addAccount() {
     for(int i=0;i<t.length;i++)
     {
       if(t[i][0]==null)
       {
        System.out.println("Enter the account no:");
        int a=sc.nextInt();
        t[0][0] = new ArrayList();
        t[0][0].add(a);
        t[0][1] = new ArrayList();
        t[0][1].add(0);
        System.out.println("Account number is:"+a +"Current balance is:"+t[0][1]);
        break;
       }
     }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You're creating a *new* `ArrayList` object each time in the loop.

Comment: isn't `ArrayList[][] t = new ArrayList[2][10];` creating a **3**-D array (including the arraylist)?

Comment: I used your code and printed t[0][0] and t[0][1] and they are being added. They are being added the the array lists at those indexes.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is not an array type. Instead of treating it like one you need to make a nested ArrayList.

```
// create
ArrayList<ArrayList<FooBar>> list=new ArrayList<ArrayList<FooBar>>();
// add to first layer
list.set(index, new ArrayList<FooBar>());
// add to second layer
list.get(index1).set(index2, new FooBar());
// etc
```

So basically in order to access the second layer of arraylists you need to use get() on the first list.

Comment: What I meant by "array type" is modifying array indices like you're doing will not actually modify the ArrayList itself. (Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding/updating only the 0th row of your 2D arraylist array, you need to change:

```
    t[0][0] = new ArrayList();
    t[0][0].add(a);
    t[0][1] = new ArrayList();
    t[0][1].add(0);
```

to

```
    t[i][0] = new ArrayList();
    t[i][0].add(a);
    t[i][1] = new ArrayList();
    t[i][1].add(0);
```

**You are not doing it the right way. you shall keep it as ArrayList of ArrayList.**

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You're using a 2D array of ArrayLists (which is essentially a 3D array) - NOT a 2D ArrayList. The item t[0][0] (or t[0][1]) is an ArrayList itself, that's why you are getting unexpected results.

If you want to use an ArrayList to make a 2D array, use it like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> t = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(20);
t.get(0) = new ArrayList<Integer();
t.get(0).add(a);
```

This creates an ArrayList of ArrayLists of Integers, which you can access using the `get(int index)` method.

If your array is going to be of fixed size, I suggest you use native Java arrays, with the `[]` notation:

```
int[][] t = new int[2][10];
t[0][0] = a;
t[0][1] = 0;
System.out.println("Account number is:"+t[0][0] +". Current balance is:"+t[0][1]);
```